# FirebaseUI 'Cannot Resolve FirebaseListAdapter Constructor'

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to use FirebaseListAdapter to create a simple ListView of all the keys, but I am facing some difficulties with the constructor.

Here is my code:

**build.gradle file firebase dependencies**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'
```

**fragment containing the list view**

```
// Only showing firebase imports
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class UpcomingBookings extends Fragment {
    private String title;
    private ListView bookingsList;
    private ArrayList<String> bookings;

    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    DatabaseReference userBookingsDatabase;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        userBookingsDatabase = mDatabase.child(userID).child("Bookings");

        // The problematic ListAdapter constructor
        ListAdapter firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(getContext(),String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,userBookingsDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_upcoming_bookings,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm getting the error `Cannot resolve constructor`, and I have already tried the methods suggested in other related stackoverflow questions (e.g using newest version of firebase, changing import statement). What should I do?

Comment: can you post full error you're getting

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Currently, the constructor arguments are underlined and I get the error `Cannot resolve constructor 'FirebaseListAdapter(android.content.Context, java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>, int, com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference)'`

Answer (score 2):

Add it to your project's `gradl`

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `FirebaseListAdapter` should be an `Activity`.  Pass in `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`